# Do loop and general loop question for updating a variable

Tags: programming, procedural-programming

My intention with the following code:

```
step = 0.1;
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 100, step}];
T = Table[0, {i, Length[time]}];
tt = Prepend[T, 90];

temp = 0;
Do[
 tr = tt[[i]]+temp;
 temp = ((tr + 273.15) - time[[i+1]]) - 273.15
   // Print, {i, 1, 100, 1}
 ]
```

is to have `tr` to be updated each time as if you were reading it line by line. In other words, to have `tr` to be in the first iteration 90, and then in the following iterations whatever the value of `temp` is in each iteration. As an example, for the first iteration `temp` should be `temp = ((90 + 273.15) - 0.1) - 273.15 =89.9`. In the second iteration `temp` should be `temp = ((89.9 + 273.15) - 0.2) - 273.15 =89.7`. In the third iteration `temp` should be `temp = ((89.7 + 273.15) - 0.3) - 273.15 =89.4` and so on. I am do not think the `do loop` is the appropiate loop for this but I am not what would be the best strategy for this. I appreciate your inputs in advanced

Comment: having hard time figuring what you want. Is it `{89.9, 89.7, 89.4, 89., 88.5, 87.9, 87.2, 86.4, 85.5, 84.5,etc....}` or something else? Answer below gives the above. May be you can give a small explicit example (say `i=1..3` only and show what list should the loop generate. This is easier than describing with words.

Comment: @ Nasser What I want is is to compute `temp=((tr + 273.15) - time[[i+1]]) - 273.15` by using updating `tr` each time. So that in the first iteration `tr=90`, in the second `tr=temp`, in the third `tr=temp` and so on. So I want 'tr' to be 90 at first by then to get the value of `temp` after the second iteration. I hope that helps clarify it

Comment: But this is what the answer below gives. Again, it will much simpler to give the ACTUAL list you want to see for say `{i, 1, 3 1} ` instead of using words to describe things. This will make things much more clear.

Comment: @Nassar Yes, that's what the code below does but it is not the same to get an answer than to compute it, right?. I just would like to perform the loop or in a line were `temp` is compute it (which the other code happens to get the answer to but it does not compute `temp`)

Comment: for `i=i` `temp` will generate 89.9, for `i=2` `temp` will generate 89.7, for `i=3` `temp` will generate 89.4. It would do so by having 'tr' to be 90 for `i=i` `tr=temp` for any iteration after that.

Comment: @ Nasser I think a made the question more clear and why I want the code to be like this in this new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/code-to-emulate-what-excel-does-in-cells. Essentially I wanted to do a loop or generate a code that can do what I am doing in two columns in excel. I hope this is better for clarification purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, something like

```
FoldList[Plus, 90, -Table[i/10.0, {i, 1, 25}]]
```

might suit your needs ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, even though your code gets the answer I need it is not using `time` and not getting the computation for `temp`. I would like to get `temp` if I were to change 'time' for some other values for instance.I would be great if that can be accomplish by getting `tr` updated each time